# Is there other way to reference grandParent object in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following code:

```
var objectParent:{
     child1:{
       test1:function(){},
       test2:function(){}
      },

      child2:{
       demo1:function(){},
       demo2:function(){},
       parent:this  // gives child2
       grandparent: .... // need to reference objectParent here

      }

    }
```

We can reference object by using **this** keyword, But what for grand object or i mean parent of parent object?

Now, i am using **grandparent:objectParent** to reference parent object

Is there other way like **this** selector to reference parentObject?

Are these my coding is bad,good or better?

Comment: I don't think that var objectParent:{ ... } is even valid syntax

Comment: Then what is valid? Should i remove var? or add something else?

Comment: It should be `var objectParent = { ... }`.

Comment: `this` won't give `child2`, it returns whatever the value of `this` is in the function you're running. You seem to be confusing object literals with object-oriented prototypes.

Comment: Just because you nest objects does not mean you're creating some form of object graph (with raw JS).  When you assign a child object you're assigning a reference to a different memory location, there is not actually a hierarchy created: just what are effectively flat references.  If you want to point to a "parent" object, then you should provide a reference to that object within the context of what you're viewing as a "child" object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all your objects have a `parent` property that refers to their parent, then can get the grandparent with `object.parent.parent`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not real clear what you're trying to do.

If you have an element reference `elem`, then you can get its parent with `elem.parentNode`.  You can get a parent's parent (e.g. a grandparent) with `elem.parentNode.parentNode` and so on.

If this isn't what you're trying to do, please explain in more detail what you mean by a grandparent object.

---

If you're not talking about DOM references at all and instead are asking about nested objects in plain javascript, then javascript does not contain any way to get the parent object that you are contained within.  You would have to create a property on the child and set it if you need it that way after you've constructed the object (you can't set it with a static declaration either).

Comment: I want to store objectParent reference inside child2 object property. I can reference by using grandparent:objectParent , but if we want to reference object we use this keyword, but what for grand object?

Comment: @blueghhgdtt - As I've said, you will have to create and set your own `parent` property in each object and then you can reference `this.parent.parent` to get the grandparent.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do `div.parentElement.parentElement` to achieve it.

One way to see what to access is by logging `div.__proto__` to the console which shows you a long list of properties & methods you can call.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to go the long way doing `div.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`. Instead you can just do `div.offsetParent` and you'll get the grandparent of the div.